# On what inherent parameters does the speed of mosfet depend in a SRAM cell circuit?

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, sram, solid-state-devices, 3d

I want to design 3D IC with 2 stages for a simple SRAM cell. Some of the MOSFETs will be on the top stage while some on the bottom stage.

The MOSFETs on the top stage are supposed to be degraded in performance compared to the MOSFETs on the bottom stage due to material fabrication issues. I want to know what exactly slows down the MOSFETs on the top stage.

Does the speed depend on the mobility of the charge carriers?
What are the main parameters that decide the speed of a MOSFET apart from its intrinsic capacitance?

Comment: What do you mean by the **speed of a MOSFET**? I wonder if you don't have a specific circuit in mind but you are just not telling us what it is.

Comment: I am talking in 3D-IC terms. I should have made it clear, sorry.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "3D IC". As far as I know the 3D stands for stacking IC dies, this bears no relation at all to a single SRAM cell. But I don't know everything so show what you mean. Before you can design anything all the things that you ask should be clear to you. If you design with MOSFETs then I expect you to **know** the answer to *Does the speed depend on the mobility of the charge carriers?* and *What are the main parameters that decide the speed of a MOSFET* Maybe you need a course on semiconductor devices?

Comment: As far as I know multi transistor layers on a silicon die are only researched in laboratories. Knowing that these companies are very secretive about their *normal* manufacturing process, I doubt anybody will tell you anything about their *research* results. (And as already pointed out to you 'speed' is not a MOSFET parameter)

Comment: If speed has no relations with a MOSFET alone, then can I consider that mobility of charge carriers does not affect the speed of the MOSFET?

Comment: Speed of the MOSFET? What's your frame of reference? I would expect the MOSFET to be stationary to it's surroundings

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about the cutoff frequency ft, defined as the frequency where the current gain of the transistor equals unity.

These formulas were summarized from *Semicondutor physics and devices* by *Neamen*:
$$
f_T=\frac{g_m}{2\pi C_{G}} \text{; where $C_G$ is the equivalent input gate capacitance}
$$
$$
g_m=\frac{W\mu_nC_{ox}}{L}\left(V_{GS}-V_T\right) \text{; in saturation}
$$

> What are the main parameters that decide the speed of a MOSFET apart from its intrinsic capacitance?

From the above formulas it can be seen that the cutoff frequency (thus, the maximum speed for the transistor) is dependent on its operating point and dimensions.

> Does the speed depend on the mobility of the charge carriers?

Definitely.

Sadly I cannot help you with 3D IC technology but I would recommend you to give the mentioned book a read, it helps with understanding the main characteristics of transistors.

Answer (score 0):

So, I got the answer to my question.

In digital circuits, 
the time required for one switching event strongly depends on the amount of drive current that can be achieved.
Delay time = CV/I.
We want to increase I.
where, C = FO4 cap of the next stage
    V = Voltage swing
    I = drive current at maximum voltage

In CMOS digital circuits this drive current is defined as the drain current of a MOS transistor with the gate and drain connected to the supply voltage, and source and bulk grounded. It is often referred to as on-state current  or simply on-current.

Parameters on which the drive current depends:

Device geometry (W/L)
Used materials (μn, Cox, Vth)
Contact resistance
Supply voltage
Temperature (Vth)
Doping profile - Shallower junctions require the introduction and activation of higher dopant concentrations to keep the resistance of the source and drain regions small so that the drive current is maximized.